# \thanks command specific to each author

Tags: footnotes, titles, amsart

What is the correct way to have a `\thanks` command for a specific author ?

I don't want to use `\author{auth1 \and auth2}` for obvious reasons (i.e. be able to distinguish the authors).

I have tried various options without success. Here is a rather minimal example where the two thanks are not attributed.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\begin{document}

\title[short title]{Longtitle}

\author[Auth1]{Surn1 Auth1}

\author[Auth2]{Surn2 Auth2}

\address[Auth1]{adr1}
\email{auth1@adr.org}
\thanks{Network1}


\address[Auth2]{adr2} 
\email{auth2@adr.org}
\thanks{Network2}


 \maketitle
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the `authblk` package?

Comment: @Jörg No -- this question is about `amsart`, which features a different syntax for `\author` and `\thanks`.

Comment: Looking at the documentation it seems a design decision; you should say `\thanks{Author 1 thanks Xyz}`.

Comment: The package's documentation (p. 5) states that "Each occurrence [of `\thanks`] will be printed as an unnumbered footnote at the bottom of the first page of the article." That seems to be happening alright, but no symbolic footnote marks are generated. The lack of footnote markers may be a design decision, as @egreg hypothesizes, or it may be an oversight/bug.

Comment: @mico is there a simple way to implement symbolic footnote marks/markers manually ?

Comment: @Mico -- the usage of `\thanks` in `amsart (and the other ams document classes) is definitely a design decision.  the transition from using a footnote marker to no marker appears to have been made during the period 1986-1988 (before the uniform use of tex to produce ams journals).

Comment: @Niels -- `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` can be used judiciously to add the markers manually.  you may have to manually adjust the value of the counter that is used for the markers to get appropriate results.

Comment: @Niels -- in your example, i notice that the content of the `\thanks`es is "Network1" and "Network2".  if that means what it appears to mean, perhaps the `\urladdr` provided by `amsart` would be more suitable.  however, that, like the addresses, will be placed at the *end* of the article.  it's possible that a different document class might match your expectations better than `amsart`, unless that's what is required by the journal to which you are submitting it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Perhaps you'd like to write a short answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the example supplied in the question has correct input, except that the author names are usually presented in "normal" order, not surname first (unless, as in chinese, the surname really *does* come first).

the `\thanks` associated with each author are placed as unnumbered footnotes at the bottom of the first page.  it is usual, with this arrangement, to say something like "The first author was supported by ...", etc., so that it is clear which acknowledgement applies to which author.

however, what i see in the example is probably a url, not a normal acknowledgment.  for this use, the ams document classes provide the command `\urladdr` which, as for e-mail addresses, is listed with the regular address; for `amsart`, this is at the end of the article.

if footnote markers are required, `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` can be used judiciously to add the markers manually.  however, you may have to manually adjust the value of the counter that is used for the markers to get appropriate results, and you will also need to supply "optional" alternates for the author names to avoid having the footote markers appear in running heads.

the arrangement described is a design decision specific to ams article classes; unless the publication to which you are submitting your article requires `amsart`, it is possible that a different document class might better match your expectations.